# Apply function n times using all previous results

Tags: python, function, numpy, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I was wondering if there is a pythonic way to apply a function several times where the **all** last results are the input again using a list comprehension or generator expression instead of a for loop like this?

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, s):
    return (5+sum(x))**(-1.06)/s

y = np.array([])
for i in range(5):
    y = np.append(y, func(y[:i], s=i+1))
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, `itertools.accumulate` seems to only consider the last, but not all last results. Any further ideas?

Comment: What's the idea behind looking for - `list comprehension or generator expression instead of a for loop`? Is it performance or something else?

Comment: Yes, there is. It is called `functools.reduce`.

Comment: Interest, performance and using a one liner.

Comment: Will this work for you? [func(range(i), i+1) for i in range(5)] and enclose it in np.array call? It relies on func expecting serial integers. If you rely specifically on the numbers already inside the list, i.e. y in your case, I am not sure you can do it in a comprehension.

Comment: @ Love Tätting this does not yield the same result as I assume it does not rely on the numbers already in the list right?

Comment: @timgeb I see, but this only gives me the final value right?

Comment: After some research I would say that `functools.reduce` does not seem to get the right result as it only depends on the last result, not an **all** past results. Unfortunately `itertools.accumulate` does the same but saving all results and not only giving the last result. Still, not the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no built-in, but it's easy enough to make:

```
def pastmap(f, inputs):
    """
    :param f: A function of the form y[i] = f(y[:i], inputs[i])
    :param inputs: An iterable of inputs
    :return: A list of length: len(inputs)
    """
    results = []
    for x in inputs:
        new_result = f(results, x)
        results.append(new_result)
    return results


def func(x, s):
    return (5+sum(x))**(-1.06)/s


y = np.array(pastmap(func, range(1, 6)))
```

Note that at least for your example, it's very inefficient to do this, because you're repeatedly taking the sum of a growing list, which is `O(N^2)` (it would be better (`O(N)`) to keep a running sum and use that)

Comment: This is just an example. Thanks for your code. One question: is that faster the the for loop? That is why I was actually looking for a list comprehension or generator expression solution. Cheers!

Comment: Probably not faster, because it's just moving the loop into a more generic function.  But also the loop is probably not the main bottleneck of your code, or if it is it should be moved into numpy or something.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the loop into numpy?

Comment: Ah well a lot of the time you can just move the loop into a numpy operation like `np.cumsum` but I admit in your case, where each output is some nonlinear function of the previous output, you cannot.  If you're in Python 2.X, and the slowness of python loops is really your bottleneck, scipy weave https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/weave.html can let you quickly iterate.